# <input type="text"> helper (fades out the text when user types) javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add helpful text (in javascript WITHOUT ANY FRAMEWORK USE) in input fields `text` and `textarea` something like this but dont know what its called

[image: me.com]

As it is used in me.com but I dont want to submit the values that are used as helpers.

Sorry for bad english.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the best way to solve this is to use an `<label>` and position it over the input area.  This gives you:

1. More aesthetic freedom
2. Keeps your page semantic
3. Allows you to gracefully degrade
4. Doesn't cause problems by submitting the tooltip as the input value or have to worry about managing that problem

Here's a vanilla version since you asked for no framework.  The markup shouldn't need to change, but you may need to adjust the CSS to work with your needs.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    label.magiclabel {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    label.magiclabel,
    input.magiclabel {
        width: 250px;
    }
    .hidden { display: none; }
    </style>

    <noscript>
        <style>
            /* Example of graceful degredation */
            label.magiclabel {
                position: static;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
</head>
<body>
<label>This is not a magic label</label>

<form>
    <label class="magiclabel" for="input-1">Test input 1</label>
    <input class="magiclabel" type="text" id="input-1" name="input_1" value="">

    <label class="magiclabel" for="input-2">Test input 2 (with default value)</label>
    <input class="magiclabel" type="text" id="input-2" name="input_2" value="Default value">
</form>

<script src="magiclabel.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

vanilla-magiclabel.js

```
(function() {
    var oldOnload = typeof window.onload == "function" ? window.onload : function() {};

    window.onload = function() {
        // Don't overwrite the old onload event, that's just rude
        oldOnload();
        var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

        for ( var i in labels ) {
            if (
                // Not a real part of the container
                !labels.hasOwnProperty(i) ||
                // Not marked as a magic label
                !labels[i].className.match(/\bmagiclabel\b/i) ||
                // Doesn't have an associated element
                !labels[i].getAttribute("for")
            ) { continue; }

            var associated = document.getElementById( labels[i].getAttribute("for") );
            if ( associated ) {
                new MagicLabel(labels[i], associated);
            }
        }
    };
})();

var MagicLabel = function(label, input) {
    this.label = label;
    this.input = input;

    this.hide = function() {
        this.label.className += " hidden";
    };

    this.show = function() {
        this.label.className = this.label.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/ig, "");
    };

    // If the field has something in it already, hide the label
    if ( this.input.value ) {
        this.hide();
    }

    var self = this;

    // Hide label when input receives focuse
    this.input.onfocus = function() {
        self.hide();
    };

    // Show label when input loses focus and doesn't have a value
    this.input.onblur = function() {
        if ( self.input.value === "" ) {
            self.show();
        }
    };

    // Clicking on the label should cause input to be focused on since the `for` 
    // attribute is defined. This is just a safe guard for non-compliant browsers.
    this.label.onclick = function() {
        self.hide();
    };
};
```

[Vanilla demo](http://jsbin.com/uqifa/)

As you can see, about half of the code is wrapped up in the initialization in the `window.onload`.  This can be mitigated by using a framework.  Here's a version using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("label.magiclabel[for]").each(function(index, label) {
        label = $(label);
        var associated = $("#" + label.attr("for"));

        if ( associated.length ) {
            new MagicLabel(label, associated);
        }
    });
});

var MagicLabel = function(label, input) {
    // If the field has something in it already, hide the label
    if ( input.val() !== "" ) {
        label.addClass("hidden");
    }

    label.click(function() { label.addClass("hidden"); });
    input.focus(function() { label.addClass("hidden"); });
    input.blur(function() {
        if ( input.val() === "" ) {
            label.removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
};
```

[jQuery demo](http://jsbin.com/oqaqu/).  The markup doesn't need to be changed, but of course you'll need to include the jQuery library.

Comment: A question can we load it without onload? Because the form I am using this helper is loaded with help of ajax and I am already using few things onload.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way:

```
<input type=text placeholder="Member name">
```

Comment: This is the best and cleanest answer, but there is a strong caveat with this in that the `placeholder` attribute is only available when using [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) as your page encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="member_name" value="Member Name" onFocus="field_focus(this, 'Member Name');" onblur="field_blur(this, 'Member Name');" />
```

Ofcourse, you would like to create input type password for the password field, so this won't be useful for the password text box.

You can also wrap this in functions if you are dealing with multiple fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function field_focus(field, text)
  {
    if(field.value == text)
    {
      field.value = '';
    }
  }

  function field_blur(field, text)
  {
    if(field.value == '')
    {
      field.value = text;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Hello this works fine but can we clear this when form is submitted like for optional fields? Also can we wrap this in function? because I have lots of input fields and textareas

Comment: Why you want to clear these text boxes? if you want to clear them before form is submitted then no data of these text boxes will be passed to the processing script.

Comment: I mean clear them if the values are default values else submit them, I will be using its a product description form and not login form, so there are lot of option fields.

Comment: @Shishant: see my answer again i have modified it. hope that helps, good luck bye and thanks

Comment: the `"document."` portion of the 4 lines in the above JavaScript is incorrect.  `field.value` works just fine.

Comment: @scunliffe: Thanks for letting me know about that, fixed it, actually i had not tried the code. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Shishant: hi i have made few corrections to javascript code, please update it if you have not done that. thanks

Comment: -1 for obtrusive event registration and creating new problems with the "tool tip" text being submitted as values.